# How to scroll to row on ios7?

Tags: ios, scroll, ios7

I have the following code to select and scroll to a given row in a UITableView:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)inAnimated
{
    NSIndexPath* me = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.someIndex inSection:0];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:me animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
}
```

This worked fine in IOS 6 but on IOS 7 the UITableView goes beneath the UITabBar.

How can I make this code work on IOS 7 and make sure that the row is really visible?

Comment: `[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:me atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES]`

Comment: No, that does the same but without selecting the row.

Comment: Have you tried a different scroll position? Maybe the frame of your table view is not as you expect?

Comment: It scrolls so that the row is just under the UITabBar.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `NSIndexPath` , instead of `NSIndexPath` use row number. 
save the index of row somewhere and use it, In iOS 7 they have changed the structure of index path.
I had the similar issue and resolved it by saving the row instead of `NSIndexPath`

Comment: The NSIndexPath is basically just the section and the row number, so I can't see how that can make any difference?

Comment: test it first, because before iOS 7 it was as you told but now it has some more values as well, you can log NSIndexPath and see the it is different from past

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you need to scroll to a point plus the height of the UITab Bar. You could try changing the offset. (I haven't tried this yet)

```
[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,tabBar.bounds.size.height) animated:NO];
[tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```

or maybe it was:

```
[tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(tabBar.bounds.size.height, 0, 0, 0)];
```